# Can airlines choose whether or not to enable MCAS on their fleets, and if so, have US airlines chosen to do so?

Tags: aircraft-design, boeing-737, mcas

I've been told that, although all 737 Max aircraft are equipped with MCAS, the system can be deactivated by the individual airline.  I've also heard that US airlines never activated MCAS in their 737 Max aircraft.  Any truth to either?

Comment: Where did you get that it can be deactivated by airlines? That's dubious since it's a part of the airworthiness certificate. There are optional AoA readouts and disagree warning lights. The latter of which, I believe, is planned as a mandatory retrofit for the new MCAS update.

Answer (score 9):

No, MCAS was required for the 737 MAX to be certified by the FAA. It cannot be deactivated by any airline, including airlines in the U.S.

---

Source:

> "M.C.A.S. was necessary then for the airplane [737 MAX] to be
>   certified by the F.A.A. to have met all of the regulatory design
>   requirements for stability and control."
>
> https://www.nytimes.com/2019/02/03/world/asia/lion-air-plane-crash-pilots.html